# Doubt regarding polar coordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates

Suppose we have a function as $r=\cos \frac{\theta}{2}$.

I know the graph is symmetric about $x$ axis. Replacing $\theta$ by $-\theta$ shows it. I want to know how the graph of this function is symmetric about $y$ axis also. Please help.

I am really not getting this. I have tried using $(-r,-\theta)$ and $(r,\pi-\theta)$.

Comment: Try using $\dfrac{\pi}{2} \pm \theta$. It should work.

Comment: Thanks man for your help

Answer (score 0):

Some polar plots are symmetric across the $y$ axis because
the radius is the same for $\theta = \frac\pi2 + \alpha$
as it is for $\theta = \frac\pi2 - \alpha,$ that is, because
$r\left(\frac\pi2 + \alpha\right) = r\left(\frac\pi2 - \alpha\right).$

This one is not like that. Except for certain special values of $\theta,$
$$r\left(\frac\pi2 + \alpha\right) =
\cos\left(\frac\pi4 + \frac\alpha2\right) \neq
\cos\left(\frac\pi4 - \frac\alpha2\right) =
 r\left(\frac\pi2 - \alpha\right).$$

Instead, the $y$-axis symmetry comes from a set of points with negative radius values that are symmetric with the points with positive radius values.
In fact for $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ you get only points on or above the $x$ axis:
$r \geq 0$ when $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$;
and $r \leq 0$ when $\pi \leq \theta \leq 2\pi.$

What you might try is to compute $(x,y)$ for $\theta = \pi + \alpha$
and for $\theta = \pi - \alpha$
(angles measured symmetrically outward from the middle angle $\theta = \pi$):

\begin{align}
&& \theta &= \pi - \alpha & \theta &= \pi + \alpha \\
x &= r\cos\theta 
& x &= \cos\left(\frac{\pi - \alpha}2\right)\cos(\pi - \alpha)
& x &= \cos\left(\frac{\pi + \alpha}2\right)\cos(\pi + \alpha) \\
y &= r\sin\theta 
& y &= \cos\left(\frac{\pi - \alpha}2\right)\sin(\pi - \alpha)
& y &= \cos\left(\frac{\pi + \alpha}2\right)\sin(\pi + \alpha) \\
\end{align}

Alternatively, take angles measured symmetrically inward from the two ends of
the range $[0,2\pi]$, that is,
$\theta = \alpha$ and for $\theta = 2\pi - \alpha$:

\begin{align}
&& \theta &= \alpha & \theta &=  2\pi - \alpha \\
x &= r\cos\theta 
& x &= \cos\left(\frac{ \alpha}2\right)\cos( \alpha)
& x &= \cos\left(\frac{ 2\pi - \alpha}2\right)\cos( 2\pi - \alpha) \\
y &= r\sin\theta 
& y &= \cos\left(\frac{ \alpha}2\right)\sin( \alpha)
& y &= \cos\left(\frac{ 2\pi - \alpha}2\right)\sin( 2\pi - \alpha) \\
\end{align}